# How can I view an Aptana 3 project on iPad?

Tags: ipad, aptana, lan

I want to view my project on an iPad over a local network. I have tried changing the IP address at the start from 127.0.0.01 to my IP address found using cmd and ipconfig but the files still won't load. Is this possible and how to please?

Comment: How do you run your server ? Do you use something like WAMP/MAMP/LAMP or AMPPS ?

Comment: No I don't run a server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to run a server using a software like WAMP/MAMP/LAMP/XAMP or AMPPS. Then you may put your website in the "compiling" folder (usually it is something like htdocs or www). And finally you can use the `http://localhost/` address.